# How can I display a gif while a PHP-embeded Ruby script runs after PHP action form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

So you go the master form, you type in your information, you click submit, action.php is called. How can I display a gif while the Ruby script part of the action.php file is running, and then after it completes display a thank you message?

Comment: What a hideous title. Although, not as bad as "A “Rose Is a Rose Is a Rose Is a Rose,” but Exactly What Is a Gastric Adenocarcinoma?"

Comment: use javascript / ajax to send the form data and display the desired image